# Laravel 5 stylesheets and scripts not loading for non-base routes

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-5

I am having trouble linking my stylesheets, scripts, and images for a non-base route in my Laravel 5 app. When I access example.com/about the scripts and stylesheets are working correctly but if I access example.com/about/something the scripts and stylesheets link to example.com/about/css/style.css rather than example.com/css/style.css

My code is as follows:

Routes.php:

```
 Route::get('about/{slug?}', ['as' => 'officerProfile', 'uses' => 'PagesController@about']);
```

PagesController.php:

```
public function about($slug = 'president')
{
    $officers = Officer::all();
    $currentOfficer = Officer::where('slug', $slug)->first();
    return view("pages.about", ['title' => $this->makeTitle('Learn About Us')])->with('officers', $officers)->with('currentOfficer', $currentOfficer);
}
```

layout.blade.php:

```
{!! HTML::script('https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js') !!}
{!! HTML::script('js/skel.min.js') !!}
{!! HTML::script('js/skel-layers.min.js') !!}
{!! HTML::script('js/init.js') !!}
{!! HTML::script('js/scripts.js') !!}
<noscript>
    {!! HTML::style('css/skel.css') !!}
    {!! HTML::style('css/style.css') !!}
    {!! HTML::style('css/style-desktop.css') !!}
</noscript>
```

For some reason Laravel is thinking the base URL is example.com/about when the loaded route is example.com/about/something. I have tried  as well but it still routes to example.com/about/images/image.jpg rather than example.com/images/image.jpg. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using relative paths and you need absolute paths. See the example below, the only thing I added is the prepended `/`

```
{!! HTML::script('https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js') !!}
{!! HTML::script('/js/skel.min.js') !!}
{!! HTML::script('/js/skel-layers.min.js') !!}
{!! HTML::script('/js/init.js') !!}
{!! HTML::script('/js/scripts.js') !!}
<noscript>
    {!! HTML::style('/css/skel.css') !!}
    {!! HTML::style('/css/style.css') !!}
    {!! HTML::style('/css/style-desktop.css') !!}
</noscript>
```

A relative path loads files related to the current path. Eg from the page `http://example.com/about/us` you can relatively load `images/logo.png` which results in the actual request to `http://example.com/about/images/logo.png`.

An absolute path is always from the hostname: same example as above but you'd load `/images/logo.png` which results in `http://example.com/images/logo.png`

Comment: Thank you! Definitely missed that while debugging.